# How can I select a row from tableA and join the next appropriate row from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with the following contents...
[image]

Above has been sorted by: CustomerID, JobType, Book and then Page

The end goal is to populate the EndBook and EndPage columns when one or both are empty (in this example every row except row #15).  Currently I'm just trying to create a SELECT query that returns then same table shown below but with the values filled out in the EndBook and EndPage columns.

The way I expect it to work is...

- EndBook would be equal to Book from the next row in the results (when sorted by CustomerID, JobType, Book, and then Page).

  - Ex: ID11 would be 'ABCD'
  - Ex: ID12 would be 'ABCD'
  - Ex: ID13 would be 'ABT5'
  - Ex: ID14 would be '' (because this was the last result of typeA)
  - Ex: ID15 would be '00A1' (left alone and not included in the query (because both ends are already filled out)
  - Ex: ID16 would be '' (because this was the last result of typeB)
  - Ex: ID17 would be '' (because this is the ONLY typeC for customer 586)
  - Ex: ID18 would be '1234'
- EndPage would be equal to Page from the next row in the results (when sorted by CustomerID, JobType, Book, and then Page).

  - Ex: ID11 would be '126'
  - Ex: ID12 would be '150'
  - Ex: ID13 would be '021'
  - Ex: ID14 would be '' (because this was the last result of typeA)
  - Ex: ID15 would be '005' (left alone and not included in the query (because both ends are already filled out)
  - Ex: ID16 would be '' (because this was the last result of typeB)
  - Ex: ID17 would be '' (because this is the ONLY typeC for customer 586)
  - Ex: ID18 would be '013'

I currently have the following query but I just can't seem to get exactly what I want.  In this latest attempt it only returns 4 results when I expect it to return a total of 9 (all but 1)...

```sql
SELECT
    job.CustomerID,
    job.JobType,
    job.Book,
    job.Page,
    job.EndBook,
    job.EndPage,
    next_inst.min_book,
    next_inst.min_page
FROM JobList AS job
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        jl2.CustomerID,
        jl2.JobType,
        MIN(jl3.Book) AS min_book,
        MIN(jl3.Page) AS min_page
    FROM JobList AS jl2
    INNER JOIN
        JobList AS jl3 ON jl3.Book>=jl2.Book AND jl3.Page>jl2.Page
    GROUP BY jl2.CustomerID, jl2.JobType
) AS next_inst ON next_inst.min_book=job.Book AND next_inst.min_page=job.Page
WHERE job.EndBook='' or job.EndPage=''
ORDER BY job.CustomerID, job.JobType, job.Book, job.Page
```

Comment: Copy and paste from your excel to here: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ and click `create table`, then use the text table in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) window function:

```
SELECT
    job.CustomerID,
    job.JobType,
    job.Book,
    job.Page,
    job.EndBook,
    job.EndPage,
    nextBook = lead(job.book) over (partition by CustomerId, JobType order by Book, Page),
    nextPage = lead(job.page) over (partition by CustomerId, JobType order by Book, Page)
FROM JobList AS job
ORDER BY job.CustomerID, job.JobType, job.Book, job.Page
```

To change `null` into an empty string you can use `coalesce()` or `isnull()`.

---

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) we can make this into an `update`:

```
;with cte as (
  select
      job.Customerid,
      job.JobType,
      job.Book,
      job.Page,
      job.EndBook,
      job.EndPage,
      nextBook = lead(job.book) over (partition by CustomerId, JobType order by Book, Page),
      nextPage = lead(job.page) over (partition by CustomerId, JobType order by Book, Page)
  from JobList as job
)
update cte
  set EndBook = coalesce(nextBook,'')
    , EndPage = coalesce(nextPage,'')
where EndBook = ''
   or EndPage = '';
```

Comment: OMG if this works for me...  I'm glad I decided to ask on SO, I would have never known about the LEAD() function!  I'm testing it out now SqlZim!  Thanks!!

Comment: @ArvoBowen If you follow the directions in my comment on your question I can provide a demo.

Comment: SqlZim, I just tested against my own DB and it does EXACTLY what I needed it to!  First time I have seen both the LEAD() function and the CTE being used...  Thanks for teaching me two important things today!  One question, why do you use the semicolons at the start of the CTE?